# C# - Need to add superscript in excel using DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, superscript

I am creating one excel using DocumentFormat.OpenXml library in C#. The problem is, I want superscript in one cell. I searched a lot but did not find any help for this. There is one class [SuperScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.math.superscript(v=office.14).aspx) in DocumentFormat.OpenXml library, but how should I use this class for superscript? 
If anyone can provide me solution/ example, it will be great help.

Comment: what is your target file format?  xslx?  docx? pptx?

Comment: Create a very small workbook with superscript in a cell (that's all you need). Save and close. Now use the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool (was installed with the SDK) and inspect this workbook. The tool will show you the underlying XML as well as the code required to create the workbook. That should reveal what you need to use to create superscripts.